# failed to open page to many redirect

Tags: php, laravel

I have problem use below code to build a login system, it failed to open page because too many redirect,  I trying to make folder path like
`admin/login`
`admin/` to AdminArticleController.php crud
and any path under `admin` should be detect logged in or not, how to fix it?

route.php

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin', 'before' => 'loginsession'), function()
{
    Route::get('/', function()
    {
        print 'article';
    });
    Route::get('/login', 'AdminDashboardController@getLogin');


    Route::post('/login', function()
    {    
    });
    Route::post('/logout', function()
{
    });
});

Route::filter('loginsession', function()
{
    if(!Session::has('loggedin'))
    {
        return Redirect::to('admin/login');
    }
});
```

UPDATE
How to check session exist when visit any file under `admin/` include `admin/login` or `admin/article/..`

```
Route::resource('admin/article','AdminArticleController');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin', 'before' => 'loginsession'), function()
{
    Route::get('/', function()
    {
        print 'article';
    });
    Route::get('/login', 'AdminDashboardController@getLogin');


    Route::post('/login', function()
    {    
    });
    Route::post('/logout', function()
{
    });
});
```

think.... the filter will be applied. but if `admin/login` is executed, there is no way he can login because the filter will redirect to the same action.

put `login` out of the **group** . like :

```
Route::get('/login', 'AdminDashboardController@getLogin');

Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin', 'before' => 'loginsession'), function()
{
    Route::get('/', function()
    {
        print 'article';
    });


    Route::post('/login', function()
    {    
    });
    Route::post('/logout', function()
{
    });
});
```

## update

As far your update, the filter **wont** be applied in Resoruce routes.

the easiest way will be

`Route::when('admin/*', 'loginsession');`

put this anywhere in your route file and done.

Comment: Thanks for reply! but how to check session exist any file under admin/ include /login and admin/article/..

Comment: any address with `admin/*` will have to go through under `loginsession` filter. you don't need to manuelly check it under every action.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a redirect loop because the `login` route is inside the filter that requires you to be logged in. If you are not logged in Laravel will go:

1. Is user logged in? No, redirect to `admin/login`.
2. Laravel then checks the `loginsession` filter and then tries to redirect **again**.
3. Go to step 1.

Move the `login` route outside of the group that has the filter `loginsession`.

This line:

```
Route::get('/login', 'AdminDashboardController@getLogin');
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! but how to check session exist any file under `admin/` include `/login`  and `admin/article/..`